# How to expose RestFull Service in Oracle OSB 12c? Getting "Error 403--Forbidden", when try to call Rest Proxy from Advance REST Client

Tags: rest, weblogic12c, oracle12c, osb

Technology : Oracle OSB 12c
Software : jDeveloper 12.2.1.1.0

I am creating REST proxy service using REST component in jDeveloper 12c.

Rest Proxy with POST method. When I run my proxy service from sbconsole, it is working fine as expected and giving me 200 "OK" message in response. I didn't add any authentication in my proxy service. Now when I try to call that same proxy service from "Advance REST Client" with same configuration (content-type: application/xml). It is giving me below error:

Error 403--Forbidden

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.

I checked that and I didn't find any issue related to authentication. Is there any configuration we need to do in weblogic server to access REST request? I also check with host name. Still it is giving me same error.

Answer (score 0):

GO to the Proxy service...
DO NOT CREATE A SESSION.
Click on the API TAB
Change publish status to Private and save.

Comment: You know!! The best way possible is to get rid off Oracle API Manager if you can.  Else if thats not possible, Then try accessing http://host:port/apimanager and check if your Rest service is published or not. If you don't find it there try with 'Publish' option on the Console and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Host header in the request.

e.g., **Host: ip:port**

IP should be of the business service endpoint and corresponding port.